# Строчка, которая изменит мир

Tags: javascript, html5

```
window.history.replaceState(state, title, url);
```

Вот она :)

state - может быть объектом, может быть строкой, что менять

url - строка, на что менять

title - новый title страницы

Недавно во всем известной соц.сети появились переходы по страницам без выключения музыки, т.е. вы ходили по страницам, url менялся, а звук не пропадал. Сначала у меня была мысль про кэширование страниц браузером, но потом отпала, слишком уж быстро и без задержек это происходило.

И вот наткнулся методом гугла на вот такую вот фичу в html5.

Есть 2 функции - replaceState и pushState:

Функция pushState добавляет запись в history браузера, в то время как replaceState заменяет текущий url.

Пользуйтесь, кто еще не знал :)

Comment: Добавлю: http://htmlbook.ru/html5/history .

Comment: Непрерывность звука с этой фичой не связано напрямую. Дело в том, что страница никуда не девается, поэтому музыка остаётся. Так что у вас всегда загружено две страницы вместо одной (это легко заметить.. иногда после обновления сначала появляется первая, а потом вторая). Так что фокус очень легко делается и без этих функций. Тем не менее, наконец-то появились нормальные функции по управлению историей.

Comment: «Так что фокус очень легко делается и без этих функций».
Ну да, только нормальные урлы сделать не получится. В чём и главная фишка описываемой штуки.

Comment: > Так что фокус очень легко делается и без этих функций.

Фокус не пройдет, т.к. URL в адресной строке останется прежним. Максимум что можно будет сделать в HTML 4, это изменит anchor.

Наглядный пример: выполните в консоли браузера `window.history.replaceState(null, null, '/hello-changed-world');`

Comment: Ну да, фокус не пройдет, мы говорим о разных вещах. Я писал о замене url, без дурацкий хэшей вида #..., а @cy6erGn0m пишет о технике ajax.

Comment: Эта великая строчка работает в IE9? Ну или более старых.

Comment: @Kremchik, только IE10

Comment: Kremchik, только что проверил. Это конечно забавно, но срабатывает один раз из 10-15 случаев. Хотя чего я удивляюсь, у ИЕ карма испорчена окончательно.

Comment: ИЕ отец всего что сейчас есть в WWW, относитесь к нему с уважением xD

Comment: Это открытие... Я был уверен, что просто не работает... Ну либо что я что-то не так делаю)

Comment: этому методу уже несколько лет, т.е. боян. см. http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: работаю на angular и reactjs, думаю можно просто использовать роутинг без перезагрузки страницы для таких целей

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Также рекомендуется ознакомиться с PJAX:

- http://pjax.heroku.com/
- https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Comment: pjax - это собственно правильное использование этих функций :)

Answer (score 6):

Мне кажется что добавить в список http://www.kendoui.com/ нужно обязательно. Очень и очень забавная игрушка.

Comment: А причем здесь штука для UI? Или там что-то есть такое для window.history?