# Переход между страницами без перезагрузки определённого блока (пример - плеер ВКонтакте)

Tags: flash-player, ajax, html, php, javascript

Собственно - сабж.
Может есть примеры реализации такого?
ВК и плеер так работает и окно с чатом, например.
Если мануалов нет, то в какую сторону копать хотябы ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копать в сторону HTML5. Здесь это уже обсуждалось, но так как нормального поиска до сих пор нет(такой камушек со свистом улетел в огород), быстро найти не возьмусь. Возможно, вам удача улыбнется. Речь шла о том, что у вас в одном окне фактически работают две страницы одновременно.

Если на древних технологиях, то по страницам надо гулять при помощи

location.hash

Тогда фактически, страница не будет перезапущена, а будет перерисовани ВСЕ, кроме плеера. Такой костыль.

UPD: Вы не поверите. [Нашел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16774/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80)

Comment: Я тоже не поверю что нашел) Помню что обсуждалось а как топик звался хз) +1

Comment: У Алекса только из-за одного этого поста лишних 150 очков. =) Вот дает

Comment: Спасибо огромное ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Возможна реализация через правильно открытый iframe, который будет уникален для каждой страницы, и жить пока живет сессия.Так будет перезагружаться только одна строчка кода, и вся информация за ней не пострадает.