# Независимость DOM элементов от 'document'

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Думаю, мало кто из присутствующих здесь не пользовался таким ресурсом как ВКонтакте.
Я обратил внимание на то, что у них музыка не перестает играть даже после перехода со страницы на страницу.
У меня варианта было 2:

1. Страница полностью формируется по средствами AJAX запросов, что позволяет не перегружать страницу => не срабатывать флэш-плеер.
2. На страницу наложено заклятие.

Так вот, я склоняюсь ко второму... так-как никакая политика безопасности не позволяет изменять локацию страницы (document.href) без ее перезагрузки (либо можно, но необходим "#" перед исходным адресом).

Вопрос:
Музыка играет непереставая, href меняется. Какая темная сила позволяет делать такое ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[А вот и оно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16774/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80)

Comment: Спасибо :))) Вопрос может быть снят )