# Смена URL при AJAX запросе

Tags: url, jquery, ajax

Я отсылаю AJAX запрос вот такого вот вида:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#blog_url').click(function(){  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "blog.php",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $(".row").html(html);  
                window.location.hash = 'blog.php';
            }
    });
});
```

Изменение URL идет но ссылка становиться вида `site.ru/blob.php#blog.php`

Подскажите, как сделать так чтобы ссылка становилась вида `site.ru/blog.php`?

Comment: return false?

Comment: добавлю:Синьер, ссылку в виде *site.ru/blog.php* вы не получите  с помощью location.hash,так как location.hash отвечает **именно** за хэш(сорри за французский) он же **anchor**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну или

```
window.location.href = "http://"+window.location.domain+"/blog.php";
```

Answer (score 1):

На ХэшКоде подобный ответ уже давался:

[Строчка, которая изменит мир](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16774/javascript-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80)

Хабр:

[Введение в HTML5 History API](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/)

Как всегда, в браузерах, которые уже давно пропахли нафталином, в частности в IE6, вся эта "радость" не работает. В последних, переход по ссылкам можно сделать через хэши **"#!"** (SEO-хеш).

Существуют множество библиотек, которые существенно упрощают работу с url-ом.

- [pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/) - не работает с хэшами (принципиальная позиция автора);
- [address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/) - работает с хэшами;
- [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/).

Ключевые запроса для поиска: **"replaceState"** и **"pushState"**.

Answer (score 0):

нет, ну почему не поискать в нете информации уже просто море!

```
window.history.replaceState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/another-new-url”);
```

Comment: Добавлю, чтоб ТС меньше голову ломал )) [HTML5-History-API](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API), внизу на странице, есть мануал на русском. Там же полезные ссылки и демо.

Comment: во-во. уж ссылки я не стал выкладывать.

Answer (score 0):

[`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), чтобы сам клик не отрабатывал, может, поможет?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#blog_url').click(function(e){  
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({  
            url: "blog.php",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $(".row").html(html);  
                window.location.hash = 'blog.php';
            }
        });
    });
});
```