# Воспроизведение звука на сайте

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте.
Пользователь включает фоновую музыку на сайте.
HTML, которым вставляется звук:

```
<audio id="player" loop="loop" preload="metadata" ><source src="/path_to_file_with_sound"></audio>
```

Вопрос: можно ли как то сделать, чтобы при переходе по сайту музыка не прерывалась?

Может быть использовать Turbolinks?

Возможно, кто-то посоветует `gem` для решения этой задачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно этот вопрос поможет: [Строчка, которая изменит мир](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16774/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80).

```
window.history.replaceState(state, title, url);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Почитаю про PJAX