# AJAX Плеер для сайта

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Добрый день.
Использую плеер SoundManager2 для сайта, но при переходе по страницам вся музыка вырубается. Подскажите, как мне сделать, чтобы плеер работал без перезагрузки страницы?

**UPD**

Сделал работу плеера через AJAX таким путем: при переходе по ссылке, с помощью скрипта подгружается только контентная часть таким образом плеер работает и не прерывается.
Но работает только при переходе на первый раздел ссылок, то есть с site.ru на site.ru/razdel, если я уже потом хочу перейти с site.ru/razdel на site.ru/razdel/razdel то все происходит с простым переходом. Поможете?))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.menuside').click(function(m) {
        m.preventDefault();
        var action = $(this).data('action');
        var murl = $(this).data('murl');
        var mid = $(this).data('mid');
        var mtpl = $(this).data('mtpl');
    $.post(document.location.href, {action:action,mid:mid,mtpl:mtpl}, function(data) {
        $('#wrapcontent').fadeOut(300, function() {
            history.pushState(null, null, murl);
            $(this).html(data).fadeIn(800);
        });
    });
    })
});
```

Comment: То есть чтобы работал как в вконтакте?

Comment: Получается да, или как тут http://tidido.com/ru/RU

Answer (score 1):

Варианта 2:

1. Сайт должен быть [`SPA`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).
2. Сохранять состояние плеера (в `localstorage`, например) и извлекать его при каждой загрузке. Но это чревато прерыванием воспроизведения и небольшими несостыковками (сохранять по уходу со страницы - `window.onbeforeunload`).

Comment: Нашел такое решение http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16774/Строчка-которая-изменит-мир На первый взгляд - то что нужно, но как прикрутить не пойму((

Comment: Это 1-ый вариант. Подменять адрес (как раз с помощью `HTML5 History API`), загружать соответствующий контент и показывать.

Comment: А как это замутить не подскажете?

Comment: @Batyabest, это большой и не очень простой вопрос. Ищите в сети как их создать.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю - нужно передать в срипт адрес страницы, получить содержимое и вывести его в нужном блоке, в том, где выводится контент. А потом с помощью функции подменить адрес в строке браузера?

Comment: @Batyabest, угу, так работают SPA; можно почитать по теме - https://habrahabr.ru/post/242429/