# Загрузка только определенных страниц сайта

Tags: html

Меня интересует такой вопрос - как реализовать такую штуку: чтобы при переходе по ссылкам внутри сайта изменялись какие-то элементы, а другие - не перезагружались...
Трудно сформулировать, но вот пример: В вк при переходе по внутренним ссылкам ссылка в адресной строке меняется, загружаются различные страницы, но при этом включенная музыка не выключается, а продолжает играть также без разрыва, словно новая страница не загружалась, а просто изменился контент на той же самой.

Подскажите, что за технологии тут, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Вроде это называется [SPA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Одностраничное_приложение) (single page application, одностраничное приложение), Фреймворки: [angular](https://angular.io/), [vuejs](https://vuejs.org/) и много других

Comment: А если приложение одностраничное, разве в адресной строке не должна быть одна ссылка при переходе, например, с из новостей в диалоги или какую-то группу и тд?

Comment: Содержимое адресной строки можно менять (без перезагрузки страницы), примерно так: [window.history.pushState](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/16774/227016)

Comment: Спасибо! Вы разрешили мой вопрос!

Answer (score 1):

**AJAX, Ajax** (*ˈeɪdʒæks, от англ. Asynchronous Javascript and XML — «асинхронный JavaScript и XML»*) — подход к построению интерактивных пользовательских интерфейсов веб-приложений, заключающийся в «фоновом» обмене данными браузера с веб-сервером. В результате, при обновлении данных веб-страница не перезагружается полностью, и веб-приложения становятся быстрее и удобнее -- Wikipedia.

Аудио вКонтакте работает с помощью html5 audio (раньше, и, возможно, в старых браузерах - flash). Текущий (или последний игравший) трек сохраняется в cookies. Как там реализовано "общение" между вкладками (в одной включил, в другой выключилось) в пределах одного окна я, если честно, не искал.

Comment: А если сохранять трек в куки, разве не будет прерывания трека в момент, когда одна страница уже неактивна, а другая еще не загрузилась?

Comment: В куках только id трека. Страница не перезагружается. В ответе же написано. Перерисовывается только часть, которая изменилась.

Comment: Как в куках может сохраняться только id трека? А как же время, на котором прервалось проигрывание? И если страница не перезагружается, то зачем тут куки вообще?

Comment: Это если закрыть браузер, а потом открыть снова, то при входе в вк в плеере в шапке будет тот недоигранный трек.